# start sed from line 1000 and onwards till end of file not working in my code

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have the follow function. I want to be able to add each of the lines in the file send by args `$3` from line 1000 but for some reason when I run the following function, it does not seem to work.

The function takes in three args, the first is the position in the line to start to adding the number from `$1`, arg `$2` is the number to add and arg `$3` is the file name. I put 1000 in the sed command but it doesnt work. Can someone help me find the issue?

```
function addusingsed {
    len_of_val="${#2}"
    insert_pos=$(($1 - 1))
    sed -i -n '1000s/\(.\{'$insert_pos'\}\)/\1'$2'/' "$3"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single number before a sed command tells sed to apply the command on *just that one line*. To process a range, you need a comma-separated pair (`1000,2000s/` etc), representing the start and end line (inclusive), and using `$` to represent the last line's address.

Also, as it stands, you won't get any output because of the `-n` option, which disables output unless explicitly requested. Probably remove it - try:

```
sed -i '1000,$s/\(.\{'$insert_pos'\}\)/\1'$2'/' "$3"
```